# Dynamic obstacles avoidance in navigation mesh system

Tags: dynamic, path-finding, unreal-development-kit, d-star

I've built my path finding system with unreal engine, somehow the path finding part works just fine while i can't find a proper way to solve dynamic obstacles avoidance problem. My characters are walking allover the map and collide with each other while they moving. I try to steering them when collision occurs, but this doesn't work well. For example, two characters block on the road while the third one's path is right in the middle of them and he'll get stuck. Can someone tell me the most popular way of doing dynamic avoidance? Thanks a lot.

Comment: You might get more answers on gamedev.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best way of doing this is to use dynamic NavMesh obstacle.

You have to instantiate a dynamic obstacle for your character and update its location with the character one each frame.

You'll find out how on the [CreatingADynamicNavMeshObstacle](http://udn.epicgames.com/Three/DevelopmentKitGemsCreatingADynamicNavMeshObstacle.html) page.